# How to Make Mandatory to pass Action name in URL(.net core mvc)?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

In MVC if we search for URL like https://localhost:3303/Home (here we just passing "Home" controller and not action) it opens index action method by default. here i have to make mandatory to pass action name otherwise have to throw error like "Please provide action name".

Comment: Remove the default Action?

Comment: @Shabbir G any update?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you want to make mandatory to pass action name otherwise have to throw error like "Please provide action name". I suggest you could try to remove the default action value in your `endpoints.MapControllerRoute` method.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
             endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
        });
```

If you want to return the custom response, I suggest you could try to use custom middleware to check if the error is 404.

Details, you could refer to below codes:

```
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await next();
            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
            {

                context.Response.WriteAsync("Please provide right controller and action name");
             }
        });
```

Result:

[image]